# AutoPrefixer for CSS Styles in the Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When developing Rails applications, I'd often use [AutoPrefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails) for cross-browser compatibility of certain styles that require vendor prefixes.

Is there an equivalent 'gem' (or 'plug') or package (something that provides the autoprefixer functionality) for the Phoenix Framework?

Comment: Are you using `brunch` with Phoenix (it's included by default unless you pass in `--no-brunch` or manually remove it)?

Comment: yes - I am using brunch

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: 
https://github.com/brunch/postcss-brunch

This should let you use the Autoprefixer with Brunch.

I haven't tried it yet but it's on the list for tomorrow.
I'll update if I run into any gotcha's, but it seems straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Phoenix use Node.js for their front-end build system - Brunch is one of the latest node.js package for that which shipped by default in Phoenix.

"**equivalent 'gem' (or 'plug') or package**" that you're looking for is a **node-package**, therefore it could be something like: **Brunch**, **Webpack**, **Gulp**, **Grunt**.

I would suggest **Webpack** if you're serious the front-end build.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. Just use [bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) or whatever, you don't need phoenix to do that for you.